# Serializable Object with Cereal

Tags: c++, templates, pure-virtual, cereal

- I have an abstract class `BaseProduct` that is inherited by classes like `ConcreteProduct`.
- I want **all** children classes to be forced to implement the `serealize` method for the `cereal` lib.
- I cant declare `serialize` as virtual because it should be a template:

```
class BaseProduct {
public:
    BaseProduct();
    virtual ~BaseProduct();
    template<class Archive>
    virutal auto serialize(Archive & archive) -> void;  // This is wrong but kind of shows what I want
}
```

So I want children to **be forced** to:

```
class ConcreteProduct {
public:
    template<class Archive>
    serialize(Archive & archive) -> void override;  // Again wrong but lets say I don't want my code to compile if this method is not implemented for this class
}
```

Is there an elegant solution to make sure all my `BaseProduct`s will be "serealizable" (cerealizable(?))?

PS: I'm just following [cereal's simple tutorials](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/quickstart.html)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using CRTP you can do this

```cpp
template<typename Derived>
struct Base {
    template<typename Archive>
    void foo() {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->template foo<Archive>();
    }
};

struct Derived0 : Base<Derived0> {
    template<typename Archive>
    void foo() {
        
    }
};
```